# How to get the path of .exe/.pkg installed on system using javascript/jquery?

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook Web Add-In using javascript/html/css. I am trying to get the path of installed .exe/.pkg file on Windows/macOS respectively on button control's click.
Please suggest solution.

Comment: No, you can't. JavaScript and jQuery cannot access local paths due to security reason.

Comment: There is no package installation in Outlook. The only thing that gets installed is the XML manifest, in the user's mailbox in Exchange. Additionally, JavaScript cannot access local paths due to security reason. What are you trying to achieve, maybe we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to download .exe/.pkg file from internet if it is not installed on my local machine on the button click of outlook addin.

Comment: Okay, this isn't supported behavior by Outlook. We are asking your intent to see *why* you want to download the exe/pkg, in case there is another way you can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Because all office addins run in a web-sandbox, it's not possible to access the users filesystem.